# Run offline web app when user is offline

Tags: html5-appcache

I'm making my web app to run offline. I have made an offline version. Now, I want to let the user know some kind of link to click to go offline page.

How I can cache the offline page whereas user is browsing online pages ??

Update:

here is the code I'm using on online version.

```
setInterval(function () {
if(!navigator.onLine){
$('.status').html('<a href="offline.html">Click here to run offline version</a>'); 
}
}, 250);
```

and offline.html contains an html file and manifest file as well.

```
<html lang="en" manifest="app.manifest">
```

UPDATE # 2
I got the solution myself. What you have to do is, put the following iframe in the online version like this

```
<body>
<iframe src="http://site.com/index.php/m/m_offline/" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```

It will cache the offline version. Remember to add the manifest file in your offline version. hope this helps to someone else as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution myself. What you have to do is, put the following iframe in the online version like this

```
<body>
<iframe src="http://site.com/index.php/m/m_offline/" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```

It will cache the offline version. Remember to add the manifest file in your offline version. hope this helps to someone else as well.